# Primefaces : lazy loaded datatable's paginator buttons not showing

Tags: pagination, jsf-2, lazy-loading, primefaces

i have previously used datatable pagination and it worked as a charm. This time i needed to use the lazy loaded pagination and its showing the first page and there are no paginator buttons. I have tried a lot of things but it just isnt showing the paginator buttons. if i change the number of rows, it works i.e the number of rows on tht page changed but the paginaotor buttons are not showing. if i inspect the datatable in chrome, it shows thr is a div for the paginator bottom

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="j_idt7:contentTable_paginatorbottom" class="ui-paginator ui-paginator-bottom ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br"></div>
```

this is my datatable

`<p:dataTable id="contentTable" value="#{chatroomBean.lazyLoadedChatroomBeans}"
               var="chatroom" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10" lazy="true"
               paginatorTemplate=" {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} "
                rendered="#{chatroomBean.chatroomSearchText!=null}">`

i am using jsf2, primefaces 2.2.1 and apache tomcat 6.

any help idea will be much appreciated. thanks

regards
khizar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its late but i just saw this question n remembered tht i had solved the prob so i thot i shud leave an answer here just in case sum1 else runs into it. the problem was tht the theme i was using cudnt find the images for the buttons, due to sum reason i cant remember now, i was not using the jar for the theme, i just added the theme.css to my project and it started working ... only problem was the links to images in the theme.css were like

> url("#{resource['primefaces-glass-x:images/default.png']}") 0 0

changed them to this

> url(images/default.png) 0 0

n it works like a charm ...

another solution (n probably the better one) wud be to add the jar for the theme in classpath and add the theme to web.xml but everyone probably knows tht ...  :)

Regards,

khizar

Answer (score 1):

I think you've run into [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1774).

From the linked-to forum discussion:

> Here is a workaround. Copy the
>   following lines in your load-Methode,
>   to update the pagination:
>
> RequestContext context =
>   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
>   if(context!=null)context.addCallbackParam("totalRecords",
>   i);
>
> The Variable i stand for the result of
>   the projections query.

Comment: thanx alot for the response. I tried it but its still not showing any buttons. using chrome to inspect the page , i see it has errors.
`//<![CDATA[
widget_contentTable = new PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable('contentTable',{url:'/mobilink_student_portal_web/list_of_chatrooms.faces',formId:'contentForm',paginator:new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({rowsPerPage:1,totalRecords:2,initialPage:1,containers:['contentTable_paginatorbottom']})});
list_of_chatrooms.faces:161Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined
//]]>`

after this line there is a **uncaught referenceerror primefaces is not defined**

Comment: @khizar: that sounds like a lower-level problem that is not specific to datatable or pagination. Do you have an entry for the Primefaces resource servlet in your web.xml? I think it's not needed with recent versions of Primefaces and can cause problems.

Comment: thanx alot man ... i finally got it to work ... i dun know exactly wat was wrong but since u said it was not the problem with datatable or pagination , i started tinkering with the jsf and i also removed some extra jquery files that were included in the template but not being used and suddenly everything started working. now i'll try and reproduce the problem later to see what exactly was wrong n post it hre so that its helpful but for now its working n i am relieved coz i am a bit behind on my deadline. so thanx a lot :)